# Extending base.html conditionally, in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Based upon whether a custom-defined context variable `{{ state }}` is `true` or `false`, I want to extend a *different* flavor of `base.html` in a Django template.

What's the Django template code to make this happen?

I'm trying: `{% extends state|yesno:"base1.html;base2.html" %}` but unsure whether this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there - you just need to replace your semi-colon `;` with a commma `,`:

```
{% extends state|yesno:"base1.html,base2.html" %}
```